# is there a token generator for CSRF(Cross-site request forgery) in the codeigniter framework?

Tags: php, security, oop, codeigniter

I wonder if there is a class in codeigniter to generate token to form
sample

```
Form Data
--token:ab664f63c186e43eb51f33c5f1a7e116
--login:admin
--senha:admin@#123
```

Comment: First google result http://aymsystems.com/ajax-csrf-protection-codeigniter-20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me google that for you... http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fellislab.com%2Fcodeigniter%2Fuser-guide%2Flibraries%2Fsecurity.html&ei=0mBHUbb5Hfe14AODyICwAg&usg=AFQjCNGAAm1mQX3ckNRIgG8HRhMdDsu_pg&sig2=JL3igdEf3JS0cJ8hhDX_VQ&bvm=bv.43828540,d.dmg